# Restore SQL database from Azure db server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I need to restore a SQL database from Azure and i don't see this database under deleted database list on the db-server from Azure dashboard.

This was deleted 11 days ago.

Request one to please let me know if there is a way i can restore this database.

Comment: I don't think that Azure   holds any backup dbs. Unless you have a local backup, I am not sure that you can restore it

Answer (score 3):

What service level do you have? This will determine the retention period for backups.

**Basic** service tier: 7 days

**Standard** and **Premium**: 35 days.

If you only have Basic, then your backups older than 7 days will have been deleted.

For long term retention:

[Store Azure SQL Database backups for up to 10 years](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-long-term-retention)